# Dynamically create webpages for different routevalues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

this is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult ShowMenu(string id)
        {
            ViewBag.Id = id;
            return View(id);

        }
```

I am basically creating different webpages based on different menus.. 
The view I created:

```
<div class="test">
    @foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Test", "ShowMenu", routeValues: new {id = "test" })</li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

So then I also created a View for ShowMenu.. but the problem is: how can I create multiple webpages for the ID's? The domain looks like mydomain.com/ShowMenu/test

The `test` will change into different values as the for loop keeps iterating, and I need to create different webpages for each of those `id` parameters.

I want to just use my *ShowMenu* View, and through that, dynamically change the webpage based on that `id` parameter

Comment: Post the route config.

Comment: You probably need to get your terminology straight. Where you say webpages, you mean URL's. Where you say domain, you mean URL. At least, I think so. Double check your words!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use some property from your DataRow, like how I access `dr["id"]` below.

```
<div class="test">
    @foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Test", "ShowMenu", routeValues: new {id = dr["id"] })</li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

By the way, passing DataTables to your view isn't very common in MVC that I'm aware of. Instead, you typically describe a model and pass that. For example

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult List()
{
    List<Product> products = Database.GetProducts();
    return View(products);
}

public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    Product product = Database.GetProducts().Where(p => p.Id == id).Single();
    return View(Product);
}
```